# efficient and clean way to prompt a user through a series of questions

Tags: c#, command-line-interface

I'm creating a command line program that does some custom file generation. It allows the user to either provide a .txt file with variables and their values, or run through a series of prompts. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient and cleaner way to prompt the user through the series of questions.

```
/**
     * InitializeVariables
     *  InitializeVariables will set a variable to its associated value
     *  
     * Parameters:
     *  variableName  - the variable we want to set
     *  variableValue - the value of the variable
     * 
     * Returns: 
     *  True if there were no exceptions detected, False otherwise.
     **/
    private bool InitializeVariable(string variableName, string variableValue)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (variableName)
            {
                case "CLIENT_ID":
                    this.CLIENT_ID = variableValue;
                    return true;
                case "PEO_CLIENT":
                    this.IS_PEO = Convert.ToBoolean(variableValue);
                    return true;
                case "INCLUDE_IC":
                    this.INCLUDE_IC = Convert.ToBoolean(variableValue);
                    return true;
                case "UNIT_LIST":
                    this.UNIT_LIST = new List<string>();
                    var uni_list = variableValue.Split(',');
                    foreach (var uni in uni_list)
                    {
                        this.UNIT_LIST.Add(uni.Trim());
                    }
                    return true;
                ....
                default:
                    // We don't care about extra anything else
                    return true;
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException fe)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("*** FORMAT EXCEPTION ***");
            Console.WriteLine("The value '"+variableValue+ "' is not valid for the variable '"+variableName+ "'.");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And the PromptUser method

```
/**
     * PromptUser
     *  PromptUser will ask the user a series of questions related to the Employee Generation File
     **/
    private void PromptUser()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Client ID: ");
            //this.CLIENT_ID = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!InitializeVariable("CLIENT_ID", Console.ReadLine().Trim())) break;

            Console.Write("Is this a PEO Client (True or False)? ");
            if (!InitializeVariable("PEO_CLIENT", Console.ReadLine().Trim())) break;

            Console.Write("Do you want to include Independent Contractors (True or False)? ");
            if (!InitializeVariable("INCLUDE_ICS", Console.ReadLine().Trim())) break;

            ....
        }
    }
```

I feel like this isn't a very clean way to accomplish this task. I'd also like a way to give the user the option of cancelling the prompt at any point by providing a specific command and with this implementation, that's another if statement for each line.

Some ideas I had were a collection (array?list?) of questions, and we cycle through each of those.

Comment: If you've voted to close this question, please indicate why so I can (hopefully) update it and address your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

One option that I see (just outlining; as I am not too much into C#):

1. Create a class tupels with 2 values:

A) The text to be displayed to the user

B) a callback method that takes the string provided by the user, and knows which field of the surrounding calls to update (and how to do that).

2. Now you create one object of that class for each "question" and put them into a list
3. Now you only need to iterate that list; you display the text; and then call the callback